# Export data in csv from dgrid OnDemandGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dgrid

I am using ArcGis JavaScript 3.5 APIs and after seaching the data from the map, i am putting the data in **dgrid.OnDemandGrid**. This everything is working fine . **I want to ask Is there any option to export the resulten data into csv file ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no option to set, I think you can develop it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth Franqueiro has a nice solutions up: https://github.com/kfranqueiro/dojo-smore/blob/master/Csv.js#L135-170

It's really based on Memory store rather than the actual dgrid, but since most likely you are binding a Memory store to your dgrid anyway this should work for you.